# MongoDB - Why should I use a cursor instead of iterator_to_array (in PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb, database-cursor

The PHP documentation for the mongo class says [using a cursor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) instead of `iterator_to_array` is superior.

Why? What benefits/flexibility will I get from that?

Comment: Fortunately, the docs have been edited since [the time this question was asked](http://web.archive.org/web/20110311120220/http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php), and they justify their advice clearly and explicitly now on the very page you've linked to.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `iterator_to_array()` makes your driver load all of the results into memory at once, and you could easily run out of memory. This would not be the case with a cursor, which uses lazy-loading!

Straight from the linked [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php):

> ```
> <?php
>
> $cursor = $collection->find();
> var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));
>
> ?>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Suppose that, in the example above, *`$collection`* was a 50GB collection. We certainly wouldn't want to load that into memory all at once, which is what a cursor is for: allowing the client to access the collection in dribs and drabs.

Comment: Im' using `$arrResults = $cursor->toArray();` and i got crash when the large records. Maybe this load all of the results into memory at once, too. How can return all values to client