# MongoDB cursor and memory

Tags: php, memory, mongodb, cursor

When I use a mongo DB cursor in php:

```
$Cursor = \MyDocument::find();

foreach ($Cursor as $Document)
    $Document->doSomething();
```

Is there then only left the last $Document in the memory or do I have to remove the built documents from the cursor object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, only `$Document` will be in memory which is the current one inside the `foreach` iteration.

As long as you're not running into *actual* memory problems, I would leave it with this simplified description.

See as well: [MongoDB - Why should I use a cursor instead of iterator_to_array (in PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060956/mongodb-why-should-i-use-a-cursor-instead-of-iterator-to-array-in-php).

The [MongoCursor class documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) explains this as well.